# Create webservice which implements a calender protocol like caldav

Tags: web-services, calendar, protocols, caldav

I'm making a calender application, which has to connect to a webservice. The webservice will get data from a third party database. Is there a way to use a calendar protocol, like Caldav, for this? If yes, how should the webservice implement the calender protocol? Does it have to use a specific library or something like that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use CalDAV and CalConnect has a CalDAV resource page to provide some information about the protocol and libraries

If you want to get SOAPy there's the [CalWS-SOAP protocol](http://www.calconnect.org/pubdocs/CD1301%20CalWS-SOAP%20SOAP%20Web%20Services%20Protocol%20for%20Calendaring%20V1.0.pdf) and you'll get schemas for that and iCalendar in XML on [the artifacts page](http://www.calconnect.org/artifacts.shtml)